# access the masterViewController from splitviewcontroller

Tags: ipad, delegates

I have started a master detail application using storyboard and core data.
     the managerObjContext is defined in the masterViewController:

```
@interface addMasterViewController : UITableViewController <NameEditorViewControllerDelegate>
    ...
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *mngObjCntxt;
```

and synthesized in the m.file:

```
@implementation addMasterViewController
...
@synthesize mngObjCntxt=_mngObjCntxt;
```

now Im trying to set the mngObjCntxt in the application deligate but with no sucess. this is what I have tried:

```
    #import "addAppDelegate.h"
    #import "addMasterViewController.h"
    #import "addDetailViewController.h"

@implementation addAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize splitViewController=_splitViewController;

@synthesize mngObjCntxt = _mngObjCntxt;
@synthesize mngObjModel = _mngObjModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoor = _persistentStoreCoor;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
   [[[splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] setMngObjCntxt:[self mngObjCntxt]];

    return YES;
}
```

the problem is that via the bolded expresion above im reaching the UINavigationController and not to the masterViewContoller, which hold the mngObjCntxt.
so Im falling on the following error:-[UINavigationController setMngObjCntxt:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
how can I access the masterViewController frm the app deligate?
thanks!
Shimrit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the class of the master view controller in Interface Builder.